# Dinamically adding objects to an existing object, and adding key/value pairs to said object

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

I have an object which already has 3 objects inside it. I want to dynamically add objects to one of those objects inside the original object, and then add key/value pairs to these dynamically added objects.

```
const result = {
    AV: {},
    Furnaces: {},
    "Production Lines": {}
};
```

So, this is the existing object with the objects inside. I add key/value pairs dinamically to "AV" easily because its simply

```
result[AV]["New key"] = value;
```

But if I try to run through a loop of the furnace names and add key/value pairs to the new object with that furnace's name, like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < furnaces.length; i++) { 

    let furnaceName = furnace[i];

    result["Furnaces"][furnaceName]["Raw Material"] = 5;

};
```

it throws an error

```
Cannot set property "Raw Material" of undefined to "270000"
```

Comment: In the `for` loop there's `funaces.length` please define `furnaces`. This line: `let furnaceName = furnace[i];` does not match with `furnaces`. `Cannot set property "Raw Material" of undefined to "270000"` is referring to `furnace[i]` probably.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Assuming you have array of furnaces. Try this,

```
  for (let i = 0; i < furnaces.length; i++) { 

    let furnaceName = furnaces[i];
    const rawMaterial = { 'RawMaterial': 5 }
    Object.assign(result.Furnaces, {[`${furnaceName}`]: rawMaterial })

};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that throwed an other error, saying the property id didn't exist.
I did however fix the issue. I added the furnaceName as an empty object before assigning new properties to it, like so:

```result["Furnaces"][furnaceName] = {};```

and then, to add the property I just added it as normal:

```result["Furnaces"][furnaceName]["Raw Material"] = rawMaterial;```